# Number of ways to pick $d$ disjoint $k$-subsets out of $n$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How many ways are there to pick $d$ disjoint subsets of $k$ elements out of a set of $n$ elements? I got

$${n \choose dk}\prod_{i=0}^{d-1} {(d-i)k \choose k}$$

Is there a closed form? Does this require the dreaded... *multinomial coefficient*?

Comment: When $k=1$ and $d=2$ your formula gives $2\binom n2$ from which I guess you want an ***ordered*** set of $d$ disjoint $k$-subsets. Is that what you intended? If not, then you're off by a factor of $d!.$ What's so scary about multinomial coefficients?

Comment: @bof You're right, also multinomial coefficients can't be put in closed form generally so it would be scary to me because I need a closed form :)

Comment: @bof Would you mind taking a look at the answer I just posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an ordered set of $d$ $k$-subsets ($dk\le n$), it should be
$$\frac{n!}{(k!)^d(n-dk)!}.$$
Thus, the number of unordered $d$ $k$-subsets is simply
$$\frac{n!}{(k!)^d \,d!\,(n-dk)!}.$$

Comment: Could you explain me why my answer is wrong, then? I would appreciate it :)

Comment: But I'm not  sure they're really different. I don't see how to compute the factorial of a binomial.

Comment: I can see now what is missing: each  (unordered) set of $d$ $k$-subsets defines a *partition* of the set of $n$ elements  into $d+1$ subsets ($d$ if $n$=kd$). So your computation is about a given partition, not about all possible partitions of this type.

Comment: Ah. Yes. I should have had the ${n \choose dk}$ as a factor out to the left and then I would have $dk$ on top. Then we have the same answer except for $(k!)^d$.... Hm... And when I think about it you're right about that. So I now concurr with your answer. Except... See my answer. I think I still may disagree. Is it possible to transform my answer into your answer just by def of binomial coefficient?

Comment: Ya. I'm certain you need to divide by $d!$. You're counting all permutations of the subsets.

Comment: You want to change the definition of binomial coefficients to make the formulae agree? :o) . More seriously, your answer f=differs from mine only a $d!$ in the denominator, which corresponds to an *unordered* set of $d!$ $k$-sets.

Comment: Ya. I mean the question was "ways to pick d disjoint subsets of k elements out of a set of n elements". So shouldn't it be unordered sets?

Comment: In my opinion too, yes. So divide my answer by $d!$.

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer and then I'll accept it? Then I can delete mine and you can have the rep, since really you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Wait, this is actually really easy. Also, the formula I gave in my question is wrong.

Namely. All you have to do is take all the permutations of the $dk$ elements, and then divide by $(k!)^d$, since each subset gets permuted, and then by $d!$, since the ordering of the subsets gets permuted. So it's
$${n \choose dk}\frac{(dk)!}{(k!)^dd!}$$

Comment: Your answer is fine if by $dk!$  you mean $(dk)!.$

Comment: @bof Thanks filllllll

Comment: Of course your answer is equivalent to @Bernard's answer, if you rewrite the binomal coefficient in terms of factorials. $$\binom n{dk}=\frac{n!}{(dk)!(n-dk)!}.$$